# Given a dynamic list of deadlines, how to trigger events at certain intervals before any deadline?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, cron, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

Say in your DB you have some "deadlines" that are subject to change:

```
deadline A: 11:30am
deadline B: 4:50pm
deadline C: 6:15pm
```

At 30 and 120 minutes before any of those deadlines, you want to send a corresponding message. You also want to send a message at the deadline itself.

```
9:30am:  "upcoming deadline A!"
11:00am: "upcoming deadline A!"
11:30am: "deadline passed A!"
2:50pm:  "upcoming deadline B!"
4:15pm:  "upcoming deadline C!"
4:20pm:  "upcoming deadline B!"
4:50pm:  "deadline passed B!"
5:45pm:  "upcoming deadline C!"
6:15pm:  "deadline passed C!"
```

In a long-running Node.js app, what's the most elegant way to schedule these messages so they deliver consistently without fail? How can you handle if these deadlines change?

Comment: What have you tried / researched so far? Share your ideas / findings / code.

Comment: what happens if a deadline is inserted less than 120 minutes before it's time ?

Comment: Then it should trigger a message 30 minutes before and at the new deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Easy thing first:  If you want your app to be reliable, then you need to use the DB to keep track of which messages have been sent and which still need to be sent. When you change a deadline in the DB, fix the pending messages and *their* deadlines.

With this information in the database, your app can die and be restarted and everything will be OK.  Every now and then it should check the DB to see if there are any messages that need sending, send them, and update their status.

The remaining question is how to schedule these checks to the DB.  With these kinds of schedules, it's probably reasonable just to check every couple minutes.  The load on the DB will be negligible, and the timing of your message sends probably doesn't need to be any more accurate than that.